# Can I use react on android? (not react native)

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

This might be a naive question but I want to know if it's possible to run react on android devices?

I'm new to react - I only know the basics of it. I know that react-native does not use html but *native-ish* objects as markup.

I just want to create a really simple app which I want to be able to access per browser but also as app.

So yeah. It's kinda hard to google this question beacuse you'll get flooded with react-native answers. Or well - maybe I just haven't tried hard enough.

Comment: Look into progressive web apps with react. They can be used to create an app-like feel that runs in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although this should **not** be considered good practice.

You can create an app that shows a [`WebView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) where you load your react code from the local file system. See also [adding ReactJS in android Webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857255/adding-reactjs-in-android-webview)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah absolutely you can run react on an Android device!

A very common way that mobile apps implement this (outside of React Native), is to have the app open a WebView – which just opens a view of a website (running React).

These apps are slower than native-ly written apps or React Native, because there's an extra layer of translation. They are typically the simplest version of an app – all they do is open the WebView and let a responsive web app take over from there.

There's even a few tools to compile a single set of source code into apps for multiple operating systems (Android and iOS at once).

[Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) and [Electron](https://electronjs.org/)(desktop) are a few popular options.